# How do you invert proportions, e.g. proportionally assign the smallest values the largest percent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is probably easier to explain with an example. Say I have a lottery and I want the poorest people to be more likely to win--in other words, I want the chance of winning to be inversely proportional to wealth.

This is confusing to me because you have to make the largest values the smallest, and the smallest values the largest.

```
Person 1: $80 - probability of winning: 20%  
Person 2: $10 - probability of winning: 40%  
Person 3: $10 - probability of winning: 40%
```

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  All you want is that probability of winning be a decreasing function of wealth?  Well, if wealth is a number in $[0,1]$ then take $p(W)=-2W+2$.  (easy to check that the area under that curve is $1$).  Or were there other properties you wanted?

Comment: Maybe you have a list of people along with their wealths and you require that exactly one person win?  In any case, some clarification would help.

Comment: My actual situation is that I have a set of quiz questions and each question has a score based on how many times that question has been answered correctly. When generating a new quiz question, I want the questions that have been aced to come up less frequently than the questions where a student is struggling.

Comment: Ok, so just do something simple:  say you have a list of weights $w_i$ for the questions.  Take some decreasing function, like $\frac 1{w_i}$  or $\frac 1{w_i+1}$ if some of the $w_i$ might be $0$.  Then let $S=\sum \frac 1{w_i+1}$  and assign question $i$ the probability $\frac 1{S(w_i+1)}$.